# Change default SQL Server timezone on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, centos, timezone

I have SQL Server installed on a Centos. I set the server date and time to my local date time and it is OK. But when I run `getdate()` in SQL Server it gives date and time based in the US time zone. I know I can get the date and with offset options but I need get the local date and time just with `getdate()`.

How can I force SQL Server to get date and time from the operating system (Centos)?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the sqlserver after setting the operating timezone and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try install tzdata :

```
yum install tzdata
```

set correct timezone:

```
rm /etc/localtime 

cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

> 

```
TZ="Asia/Shanghai"
```

then run tzselect choose correct timezone:

```
tzselect
```

finally, restart mssql:

```
sudo systemctl restart mssql-serer
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)